# Is there a way to make Spyder's Variable Explorer to display variables in global scope when "Directly enter debugging when errors appear" is enabled?

Tags: python, debugging, spyder

I'm using Spyder and having the "Directly enter debugging when errors appear" option enabled. When that happens, the Variable Explorer would show the variables that are causing the issue. But often the associated code line would be in one of the packages that I'm using, and the variable names would not make much sense to me. Plus the bug is likely in my code, not in the packages. Is there a way to make Spyder's Variable Explorer to display variables in global scope instead?